# ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 conversion in PHP

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

I have a string which is encoded in ISO-8859-1 and I need to convert it to UTF-8

This is the original string:

4055765204275;261270001;
;Cannes;6138;Beige;38;261270001-6138-38;199,9;199,9;80;61%
Baumwolle 39% Polyamid;100% Acetat; ;
;FS16;70;116;FS16Jacken & M�ntel;1;EUR;DE;
;0,6;Black;Jacken & M�ntel;Stepp & Daune;
;0010001001001001;261270001; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ;
; ; ;86

This is the converted string:

4055765204275;261270001; ;Cannes;6138;Beige;38;261270001-6138-38;199,9;199,9;80;61% Baumwolle 39% Polyamid;100% Acetat; ; ;FS16;70;116;FS16Jacken & Mï¿½ntel;1;EUR;DE; ;0,6;Black;Jacken & Mï¿½ntel;Stepp & Daune; ;0010001001001001;261270001; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ;86

This is my code:

```
$content = "4055765204275;261270001;
;Cannes;6138;Beige;38;261270001-6138-38;199,9;199,9;80;61%
Baumwolle 39% Polyamid;100% Acetat; ;
;FS16;70;116;FS16Jacken & M�ntel;1;EUR;DE;
;0,6;Black;Jacken & M�ntel;Stepp & Daune;
;0010001001001001;261270001; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ;
; ; ;86 ";
echo $content;

$str = utf8_encode($content);

echo "<hr>" . $str . "<hr>";
```

Obviously the � are not converted correctly...

What is wrong?

Comment: It seems that your original string contains a UTF-8 replacement character (`"\xEF\xBF\xBD"`) which is then double encoded. If you have questions about encodings, it's better to post hex dumps of your data, using `bin2hex`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

If the replacement character (�) is showing up in your source code that means your editor itself has the wrong character encoding expectations.   I'm not sure what you're using but you'll need to look in your editors settings about expecting a utf8 encoding to begin with.

Edit: Or if the raw source you were copying from had the replacement character the problem is with that source and there's no reverting.